# Laravel - can't get values from multidimensional array with blade

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-blade

I am having trouble looping through a multidimensional array with blade in laravel. I am sending the data from the controller like so:

```
return View::make('store.categories')
            ->with('brands', $brands);
```

And if I die dump the data:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'Fender' (length=6)
      1 => string '(2)' (length=3)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'Gibson' (length=6)
      1 => string '(1)' (length=3)
```

I've tried to use two `@foreach` loops but I couldn't get it to work:

```
@foreach($brands as $brand)
  @foreach($brand as $b)
  {{$b}}
  @endforeach
@endforeach
```

The above will output: `Fender (2) Gibson (1)`.

---

I tried to get the 0 value for the `$b` to output `Fender` but it just prints the 0 position character for each of the items in the `$b` array:

```
@foreach($brands as $brand)
  @foreach($brand as $b)
  {{$b[0]}}
  @endforeach    
@endforeach
```

The above will output `F ( G (`.

---

In my controller if I do:

```
foreach ($brands as $b) {
    foreach($b as $key=>$v) {
       dd($v);
    }
}
```

it will output `string 'Fender' (length=6)`, which seems like the second loop inside the first `@foreach` works. Although, when it comes to the blade code mentioned above it doesn't.

*I'm probably doing something terribly wrong. How can I get the output for the values 0 and 1 for the nested arrays individually? Any help is highly appreciated.*

---

This is how I create the data in my controller's function:

```
$products = Product::with('brand')->whereIn('category_id', $children->lists('id'));
$brand_ids = array();
$brands = array();

foreach ($products->get() as $p) {
    $brand_ids[] = $p->brand_id;
}
$brand_count = array_count_values($brand_ids); 
foreach ($brand_count as $key=>$value) {
    $query = Brand::where('id', '=', $key)->lists('name');
    // dd($query);
    foreach($query as $key=>$name) {
        $array = array(
             $name,
             '('.$value.')'
            );
        $brands[] = $array;
    }
}
```

Comment: Using dd doesn't prove it works.  dd ends execution, you'll still get four strings instead of the two you seem to be after (Fender and Gibson) if you use two foreachs.

Comment: Yes, you only need the one foreach.  The question is why it is coming up as `[` in the view.

Comment: Is there something wrong with the way I use to generate the `brands` data?

Comment: @cchacholiades what is your desired output? what are you trying to generate in the blade?

Comment: Sorry @PawelBieszczad I am trying to access the brands `array` position `0` and `1`, so for example the first time it loops `{{b[0]}}` outputs `Fender` and `b[1]` outputs `(2)`, the second time `{{b[0]}}` outputs `Gibson` and `b[1]` outputs `(1)`

Comment: I know, but are you trying to create a select box or something? seems like your doing a lot of unnecessary work in the controller. Cleaning it up might fix it.

Comment: @cchacholiades I understand you code, what I dont know is how are you outputting it in the view (selectbox, list of all the brands with their ids). I created an answer, did you check it out? Hope it clears some things out for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Controller

```
$brands = Brand::whereIn('id', $brand_ids)->lists('name', 'id');
```

Blade

```
@foreach($brands as $id => $brand)
    Id: {{$id}}, Brand: {{$brand}}
@endforeach
```

This should work and save you performance, cause we query all the brands instead of each one individually. A better approach would be to have the products relation set up and get them that way.

Answer (score 0):

```
@foreach($brands as $brand)
  {{$brand[0]}}
@endforeach
```

You need to look at how the array is organized.  Once you dig into the first level, 'Fender' is at offset `[0]` and '(2)' is at offset `[1]`, so you only need one foreach.

The reason you were getting `F` is because you were getting the offset `[0]` on the **string** 'Fender' (or in other words, the first letter) because the second foreach was bringing you four strings, not arrays.

```
$brands = [
  0 => 
    [
      0 => 'Fender',
      1 => '(2)'
    ],
  1 => 
    [
      0 => 'Gibson',
      1 => '(1)'
    ]
];

var_dump($brands);

foreach($brands as $brand) {
  echo $brand[0]."\n";
}
```

Outputs:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "Fender"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "(2)"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "Gibson"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "(1)"
  }
}
Fender
Gibson
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried this and it returns: `[ [`

Comment: I don't see how that is possible given the data present.

Comment: I don't have any Laravel setup to test it, but the PHP checks out as proven in my edit.

Comment: Add an update with your exact code and a dump of $brand inside the foreach.

Answer (score 0):

as you want to get the 2nd level values of multi dimensional array, and if you know that 2nd level will have only two values, then why don't you try

```
@foreach($brands as $brand) 
    {{$brand[0]}} {{$brand[1]}}
@endforeach
```